# Lotus Notes 8 rendering <script> tag contents

Tags: javascript, html, lotus-notes, newsletter

I am developing a newsletter and I'm having to support ancient POS email clients such as Lotus Notes 8 and there's a strange issue whereby the contents of  tags are written out as text.

There is a  tag in the email, but the contents is not being rendered. This suggests to me that Lotus Notes 8 is not Javascript aware at all.

Is there a workaround in which the Javascript won't run (obviously) but it also won't render the text on the page as shown in the screenshot link below?

Note: I have tried style="display:none" on the  tag but to no avail.

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4754476/Screenshots/Untitled.png)

Edit:

I've solved this by keeping the Javascript in an external file. I'm aware it won't run on email clients, the purpose of the script is to track people accessing the email via HTTP.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Prepare yourself: http://pastie.org/5616536

Comment: First of all, Lotus Notes 8 is not "ancient". Secondly, it is typically used in large enterprises, and there is a decent possibility that the content that you sent may have been preprocessed by security software before it even gets to the Lotus Notes client, so without having the Lotus Notes user capture the MIME source for you there's really know way to tell what's really happening.

Comment: Thirdly, there is an excellent chance that the security filtering in Lotus' web mail system (known as iNotes, or DWA, depending on the version) will disable your script when accessed via HTTP.  And frankly, this should be true of all enterprise-grade web mail systems, and hopefully consumer-grade web mail systems as well.

Comment: A word of advice, when asking for advice on how to code from experts in some software, it is usually imprudent to refer to that software as a POS. I'd suggest -- http://www.amazon.com/How-Win-Friends-Influence-People/dp/1439167346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't work in email. Email only supports html and limited css.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though your script relies on the end user having several Javascript libraries loaded locally, such as

```
<script src="/glb/js/libs/webtrends.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>
```

Now, I could easily be wrong, but my understanding is that this src definition will look at the root of whichever server on which the user opens the email and try to find webtrends.js in the /gl/js/libs directory. Since one never knows what end users in the wild will have loaded locally, I would expect that a full URL for the source would be a more reliable option.

While that doesn't affect whether it opens in Notes mail, it will affect whether it runs on machines other than your own.